# Can I use loops in HQL queries on Hive?

Tags: sql, loops, hive, hql, hiveql

I would like to select entries from Hive tables with different date extensions (e.g. mytable_20170205, mytable_20170206 ...). Is there any way I can loop through the dates?

Pseudocode:

```
x = 20170205
for x in range(20170205, 20170228):
   SELECT 
       x AS date
       , COUNT(user_id) AS users 
   FROM CONCAT("mytable", x)
   x = x+1
```

Comment: It seems you have a really bad data modeling. A single table partitioned by date seems to make much more sense.

Comment: Tables become too big if we add new entries each day... any ideas for the loop question?

Comment: I don't get the meaning of "tables become too big".